# Architecture Mismatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop

We have Windows Server 2018 R2 with 64 bit architecture and the Office installed on the same architecture is Office 2013 32 bit version. I have an Asp.Net application hosted on the server which takes and Excel file and parse it and accordingly. Now, the server is creating problems to create a new Excel Application object. Please give me a work around.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: The threading model of ASP.NET and Office are **incompatible**. You are really subverting the nature of the two architectures to get them to communicate properly.

Comment: Have you seen the `System.IO.Packaging` NuGet package for reading `XLSX` files directly?

Comment: Unless you do trivial stuff, System.IO.Packaging doesn ot help - the XML is complex enough to make people cringe.

Comment: @TomTom - I agree, but it is the prescribed solution for server access to Excel files from Microsoft, afaik.

Comment: @TomTom is correct, you should use a library for this and you will not need Office installed on server. Until then what you can do, if adding the library is a lot of work, you can set you ASP.NET app to run in 32bit instead of 64bit, if possible, and the error should go away.

Comment: @MihailStancescu - You might as well advise that the OP run with scissors and find gas leaks with a lit match. There's no good way to get the Excel app running on the server.

Comment: @Enigmativity I know, but I've said if time is not available to use a library and it needs a temporary workaround until they can change that.

Comment: @MihailStancescu - I understand, but how many temporary solutions stick around because, well, it seems to work ok. It's best to avoid the temptation and not even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a library to do your office work.

Office Interop does not work - you could install Office 64 bit to work around, BUT....

...Office is EXPLICITLY not supported on server environments like that. Period. RTFM style period - no support, may stop overnight. Everyone else works around this by using either office server or more likely to use a thiurd party library to do the excel manipulation.